# Structural Highlighting in Vim

Tags: visual-studio, vim, coding-style, highlighting

I have seem some cool Structural Highlighting in Visual Studio (might be using CodeKana). Can I achieve same type of Structural Highlighting in vim ? For any language. I am a python developer I would love to have it for Python. 
[image]

Comment: I think I have an answer for this here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13633152/1000282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *almost* emulate this via `listchars` by using hard tabstops instead of spaces for indentation.

Something like this should suffice:

```
set noexpandtab
set list
set listchars=tab:\|
```

Note that there is a space after the | character.

You can pick a better character to get a connected line, but this is just an example.  Also note that this will not continue the lines with no indentation, so you may end up with something like:

```
if foo:
|   bar

|   baz
```

...unless you add a tab on the blank line.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be great solution.

Answer (score 0):

What OP asks for is definitely not built in.  I assume someone could add it as a plugin extension.  An existing plugin does do multi-color highlighting of parens that is somewhat similar, maybe it could be used as a base to build a more full-fledged solution:

[RainbowParenthesesInVim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1230)