# In VIM, is there any way to define syn region for template angle brackets without clashing with less than sign?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

As for `{`,`}` and `[`,`]` and `(`, `)`, I really would like to be able to define `syntax region` for `<`, `>` to be used for C++ template usage like the following:

`a<b>`

But, is there any way to create such a syntax region without it clashing with something like the following:

`if( a < b<c>::d )`

The first `<` is clearly a "less than" operator, and should be discarded as being the beginning of a region for template parameters.

I've tried to use several options but was unable to make it work. Trying to use complex regex to identify the template args region and not a less than operation really seems impossible, it would work only by checking balanced pairs using nested self referential patterns.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @ingo-karkat answer, I thought a bit further about whitespace usage and I think I got a good enough matching pattern to be happy with (I think this catches 90%+ of the cases).

```
syn region AngleBrackets matchgroup=AngleBracketContents 
start='[[:space:]<]\@<!<<\@!'
end='>'
```

`start` matches `<` that's not *preceded* by whitespace nor `<`. Checking for being or not ***preceded*** by whitespace is a key factor because most of the time relational operations will be surrounded by whitespace and also, it is very common practice do not precede template opening brackets with whitespace.

I also check for it not being immediately followed by another `<`.

Here's a snapshot of [what I'm doing](https://github.com/oblitum/rainbow) (operators inside the region get the color of the region, nested regions change color, it's built upon Rainbow Parentheses Improved with some minor corrections):

[image: VIM snapshot]

#### UPDATE

Just changed my VIM regex to:

```
\v%(<operator\_s*)@<!%(%(\_i|template\_s*)@<=\<[<=]@!|\<@<!\<[[:space:]<=]@!)
```

This last one will actually help me enforce good code style.

Comment: Hey, I have a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052044/vim-folding-with-rainbowparentheses   I like yours the most because it does a great job of highlighting things with the right color using a dark background, right off the bat. But I have an issue...

Answer (score 1):

As long as you shoot for the *80% solution* and restrict the text inside the `<...>` to non-whitespace identifiers (assuming your coding style surrounds the comparison operators with whitespace), by using `:syntax match` instead of `:syntax region` (which already triggers on the start match, without checking for the existence of an end match), that should work (because the single regexp must match both begin and end).

A lot has already been said about the difficulties of parsing C++ (in a real compiler), so don't expect a general-purpose parsing solution using regular expressions to be perfect. (Also, don't forget that syntax highlighting merely is a visual *aid*, which you shouldn't rely on too much).

Comment: Thanks for the advices Ingo, for me it's not a matter of relying on it to code, it's because I just wanted this feature. `:syn match` won't help, because I'm doing more stuff with the contents of the region. Anyway, I know I could still use look aheads for brackets followed by spaces with regions. But it seems spaces solely are not a good discrimination rule...

Comment: A lot of people put spaces surrounding template parameters

Comment: The question is: do you? A lot of people don't seem to need special highlighting to recognize template parameters :-)