# Vim Folding with RainbowParentheses

Tags: c++, vim

So, I've looked everywhere for a good rainbow parentheses plugin that will give different level parentheses different colors. I really like the [couple that I've found](https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim), because they both do a good job of customizability while [highlighting the right thing](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Rainbow-Parentheses-Improved-and2). It supports more than parentheses; chevrons, braces and brackets all get highlighted, which I really like.

It seems like there are [quite a few plugins for this!](https://github.com/oblitum/rainbow); I'm currently using oblitum's because his is optimized for dark backgrounds (I often work straight from the shell).

So, following the tip at the github for that plugin, I have the "always on" snippet in my `.vimrc`. But when the always on block is above "syntax enable" it doesn't show `{}` as being highlighted for cpp files. When the always on block is below `syntax enable`, folding doesn't work. I think its the nature of the plugin that makes it do this; it goes though the file and adds coloration information. I notice that if I use the command `:syntax enable` after I've loaded the file when its not recognizing folds, then it *does* recognize the folds. But at this point, it removes the coloration that rainbow parentheses put on it.

In my `.vimrc`, I have the follow pertinent lines:

```
syntax enable
set foldmethod=syntax
set foldenable
set foldlevel=100

let g:rainbow_operators=2
au FileType c,cpp,objc,objcpp call rainbow#activate()
```

I think that, from looking at syntax files that come with vim, such as c.vim, you can see that certain blocks are annotated as folding. I bet that if you could just write a regex based upon it, you could identify characters as syntactic groups. Then you could just define a colorscheme for it. In fact, the [rainbow plugin](https://github.com/oblitum/rainbow) is actually calling "syn region" commands, so I think that this route is very doable, I'm just not that knowledgable with vim scripting.

Can anybody help me modify possibly the plugin or come up with a script or something that achieves both?

Comment: I recommend changing `rainbow#activate()` to `rainbow#load()`. `activate()` sometimes loses reloading of highlighting, `load()` forces the highlighting reload when needed. At my `.vimrc` I use `set foldmethod=marker`, `syntax on` and use it "bellow". I've no issues with folding...

Comment: Well, how do you have foldmethod=marker and yet work with C++ at the same time?

Comment: Ah, if you set foldmarkers={,} it does it for functions and class definitions. But what about comments?

Comment: I don't feel the need for too many folds. I also haven't played much with them.

Comment: Aww :/ Well, I just have an itch to make it work perfectly. If you haven't noticed, there are multiple plugins similar to yours, but none have bothered to address this, that's why I felt it appropriate to bring it up here. I guess the only other way to do it, would be to merge your plugin into syntax highlighting so that coloring []{}()<> happens by default, or to modify whatever the syntax settings are within vim so that they work for folding with colorful {}()[]<>. latter way sounds better...

Comment: In fact, to do the latter one could go into c.vim that is provided in the default vim syntax files and find out what happens when you use the foldmethod=syntax, and find out what is being added to the buffer by reviewing your code in order to understand why its not working. I would try, but I'm short on time

Comment: Right now, I may not look into this, but I'm interested and may check it later. I envite you to open an issue for this ;-)

Comment: How do I open an issue?

Comment: Ok, so reading over the the c.vim syntax that comes with vim, youc an easily see that certain blocks matched by regex's are denoted as folding blocks. I bet that a syntax file could be written that could be loaded for certain filetypes (or not loaded for certain filetypes if that's better), and then  you could define a recursive matcher for the symbols and put them in syntactic groups/(regions of 1 character). Then you could just define a colorscheme for it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry the lateness, I've tried to solve it at [Fix disabled folding (issue #2)](https://github.com/oblitum/rainbow/commit/088a1fa5c0995fa77eb8f848b104833cc66c1165)

Answer (score 0):

I dimly remember having had the same or a similar problem.
Also XML code highlighting was broken IIRC.

I put 'always on' off, and activated the colored parentheses only when I needed it.
So my working solution was just a shortcut to toggle the plugin on and off.

Comment: Well, I want both to work at the same time. I appreciate it though.

Comment: Believe me, I do understand you. Just sometimes you got to draw a line and stick with a workaround, when you do not have the time/resources to fix things. Vim's git plugin "Fugitive" by Tim Pope and Steve Losh's Splice plugin (Three-way-diffing) do not work well with each other, segfaulting and stuff. I love both deeply, but no way I could discern the problem source... Makes me very sad, too.